# Constraining two vectors to be in the same domain but not be member's of each other

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I've used clojure for a while but just starting out with core.logic.

Given a domain like `1 2 3 4` I want to get a vector of two vectors back like `([[1 2] [3 4]])`.

*Note: This is just a simplified version of what I'm really trying to do. :) See: https://github.com/adamhoward/lineup*

I found this definition for not-membero on the web:

```
(defne not-membero [x l]
  ([_ []])
  ([_ [?y . ?r]]
    (!= x ?y)
    (not-membero x ?r)))
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
(run 1 [q]
     (fresh [w x
             y z]
            (== q [[w x]
                   [y z]])
            (infd w x y z (domain 1 2 3 4))
            (everyg distinctfd [[w x] [y z]])
            (everyg #(not-membero % [y z]) [w x])))
```

Running this in Emacs gives me an `Evaluation aborted.` message.

When I try switching out `membero` for `not-membero` I get back `([[1 2] [1 2]])` which makes sense to me. Every element in the first vector `[w x]` is a member of the second vector `[y z]`.

**But**, when I call `run 2` I get back `([[1 2] [1 2]] [[1 2] [1 3]])`. I don't understand how `[[1 2] [1 3]]` can be correct for the rules above. Am I not understanding `everyg` correctly? Any guidance (including rtfmanual, rtfbook, rtfdissertation) will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:** May have solved this.

Still not sure about the strange results from `membero` but instead of the `not-membero` goal I found that I could do this:

```
(everyg #(distinctfd (conj [y z] %)) [w x])
```

Each element of `[w x]` conj'd to `[y z]` contains all distinct values. This may be less efficient than not-membero so I'm still open to any help.

Comment: If you think you've solved it, please post the solution as an answer (yes, it's okay to answer your own question)!

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to be doing the same as this:

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [w x y z]
    (fd/in w x y z (fd/domain 1 2 3 4))
    (== q [[w x] [y z]])
    (fd/distinct [w x y z])))
```

But seeing the soccer problem...

```
(ns test
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [==])
  (:use clojure.core.logic)
  (require [clojure.core.logic.fd :as fd]))

(defn game [g] (fresh [a b c d e] (== g [a b c d e])))

(def players (range 1 11))

(defne not-membero [x l]
  ([_ []])
  ([_ [?y . ?r]]
    (!= x ?y)
    (not-membero x ?r)))

(defne plays [player games]
  ([_ []])
  ([_ [?f ?s . ?r]]
   (membero player ?f) ; if you play this game
   (not-membero player ?s) ; do not play next game
   (plays player ?r))
  ([_ [?f ?s . ?r]]
   (membero player ?s)
   (not-membero player ?f)
   (plays player ?r)))

(defne goalies [games]
  ([[[_ _ _ _ ?a]
     [_ _ _ _ ?b]
     [_ _ _ _ ?c]
     [_ _ _ _ ?d]]]
    (fd/in ?a ?b ?c ?d (apply fd/domain players))
    (not-membero 1 [?a ?b ?c ?d]) ; star player != goalie
    (fd/distinct [?a ?b ?c ?d]))) ; not goalie twice

(defn -main [& args]
  (run 1 [q]
    (fresh [a b c d]
      (game a)
      (game b)
      (game c)
      (game d)
      (== q [a b c d])
      (goalies q)
      (everyg #(plays % q) players))))
```